# Developer program company renewal

Tags: ios, iphone, iphone-developer-program

I have apple developer program for my company and have been working on for less than a year and everything is going fine and have many applications approved and ready for sale.

my issue is that I am shutting my company and opening a new one in a different country with the same name but I want all my applications with their review and ratings. what should I do

1) can I renew my apple developer program with the new company papers (actually I dont know what apple asks for renwal, does it asks for papers again or not).

2) If I closed my company will my account also be closed with all its applications, or I can renewal it.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this: [Account Management](https://developer.apple.com/support/ios/account-management.html) FAQ:

> Please contact us for assistance with:
>   - Address changes
>   - Contact information updates
>   - **Company/Organization name updates or changes**

So you should contact apple with this problem and not us …

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation together with my partner. We contacted Apple and asked them how we could solve this problem. They where very kind and helped us.

Comment: but during the changes do they close the provisioning portal or limit you of uploading new applications